# Flexible File Writer does not create file in distributed mode on a slave machine

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Flexible File Writer does not create file in distributed mode on a slave machine.
Any help would be truly appreciated.

No exceptions are seen on jmeter-server logs on slave machine.

Comment: you need to check the path mentioned to create the file is available in the slave machine or not.

Comment: The path is available. I am able to copy files to that location from command prompt from a different machine.

Comment: Then file creation should not fail... Have you tested your script on Controller?? more over kindly share the code if possible.

Comment: What do you mean testing script on Controller? I am using a Configuration like Simple Controller>Dummy Sampler>Flexible File Writer. I will create a demo for the structure I am using and share it with you

Comment: By controller I meant the Master.

Comment: @JmeterPerfTest: Yes I have tested on controller. It still fails. Now I;m using an alternate solution to create files on master and then distribute it using Java to other slave machines as a workaround.